# Java program gets stuck while making HttpGet requests in a loop

Tags: java, network-programming, httpclient, web-crawler

I have to hit the public function(downloadDataQUANDL) about 1500 times in a loop to download data.
But my program after running for about 50-100 network calls, gets stuck randomly on one url.
Not sure why it is getting stuck as there is a maximum number of retries defined. So after exhausting all the attempts the program should skip and move to the next url.

Any ideas to fix the issue? please help

```
public List<Record> downloadDataQUANDL(String symbol){
        List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
        Calendar fromdate = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromdate.add(Calendar.DATE, -365);
        Date todate = new Date();
        String url = getFeederURLQuandl(symbol, new Date(fromdate.getTimeInMillis()), todate);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try{
            HttpResponse response = retryQuandl(url);
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(line.charAt(0))) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    String[] values = line.split(",");
                    Date date = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(values[0]);

                    records.add(new Record(date, Double.parseDouble(values[1]),
                        Double.parseDouble(values[2]), Double.parseDouble(values[3]),
                        Double.parseDouble(values[5]), Double.parseDouble(values[6])));
                }

            }else{
                System.out.println("Data fetch failed for " + symbol);
                return null;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Data fetch failed for " + symbol);
            return null;
        }
        return records;
    }


   private HttpResponse retryQuandl(String url){
        RequestConfig requestConfig =           RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(30*1000).setConnectTimeout(30*1000).build();
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        System.out.println(url);
        int responsecode=0;
int nooftries = 1;
        HttpResponse response=null;
        while(responsecode != 200 && nooftries <= 5){
            try{
                response = client.execute(request);
                responsecode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            try {
                Thread.sleep(nooftries * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            nooftries++;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: so where is it getting stuck?

Comment: When I run into network programming problems like these I always use Wireshark to help figure them out. With Wireshark you can see what is flowing over the NIC.  Usually will give good clues to what is happening right before a hang.

Comment: After increasing the JVM size, the program does not stuck now. Though the program is still slow, will introduce multiple threads to optimise the code